# How do I implement Ctools plugins from other modules?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I have a module which defines a plugin. Using this code, I can easily load the plugin:

```
ctools_include('plugins');
ctools_get_plugins('mymodule','myplugin');
```

That works great, but I would like my module to use plugins from other modules of type 'myplugin'.

I can only seem to get it to load plugins defined by the module provided in the first argument whereas I want to get all modules that provide plugin "myplugin", is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you shown, you get all the plugins of that type implemented by any module, not just from one module. In fact, when I execute the following code, I get the plugins implemented also from the Views UI module.

```
ctools_include('plugins');
dpm(ctools_get_plugins('ctools', 'export_ui'));
```

[image: screenshot]

The module name passed as first argument to `ctools_get_plugins()` is used to namespace the plugin type: There can be other modules that implement a "export_ui" plugin type, and that is the reason why the function requires the name of the module defining the plugin type.

See also the description given for [hook_ctools_plugin_directory()](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/hook_ctools_plugin_directory/7):

> This hook is used to inform the CTools plugin system about the location of a directory that should be searched for files containing plugins of a particular type. CTools invokes this same hook for all plugins, **using the two passed parameters to indicate the specific type of plugin for which it is searching**.

Comment: Thanks for this. I realised that the issue I was having was that my plugin filenames were the same and so were getting merged. I still must be thinking of plugins in the wrong way though because I would have thought that I could have had plugins from multiple modules using the same filename but everytime I do they arent returned.